# How to cancel a script after it has started Lua

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

If I start my script then realise I pressed the wrong button, or don't want it to run all the way to the end, can I add something to the code that if I press the button again, or another button if it can't be the same, it will immediately stop the script?

This is my current script

```
    if (event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == 4 and GetMKeyState("kb") == 3) then 
    MoveMouseTo( 36165, 57821)
    Sleep(math.random(10, 25))
    PressMouseButton(3)      
    ReleaseMouseButton(3)
    Sleep(math.random(40, 135))
    MoveMouseTo( 36131, 59461)
    Sleep(math.random(30, 65))
    PressKey ("lalt")
    Sleep(math.random(30, 65))
    PressKey ("X")
    Sleep(math.random(30, 65))
    ReleaseKey ("lalt")
    ReleaseKey ("X")
    PressMouseButton(1)
    ReleaseMouseButton(1)
    Sleep(math.random(2220, 2270))
    MoveMouseTo( 38932, 56060)
    Sleep(math.random(10, 25))
    PressMouseButton(1)
    ReleaseMouseButton(1)
    Sleep(math.random(40, 135))
    MoveMouseTo( 2595, 3037)
    Sleep(math.random(40, 135))
    PressMouseButton(1)
    ReleaseMouseButton(1)
    MoveMouseTo( 4166, 1518)
    Sleep(math.random(250, 350))
    PressMouseButton(1)
    ReleaseMouseButton(1)
    MoveMouseTo( 38932, 56060)
    Sleep(math.random(40, 135))
    PressMouseButton(3)
    ReleaseMouseButton(3)
    Sleep(math.random(40, 135))
    MoveMouseTo( 38590, 57882)
    Sleep(math.random(40, 135))
    PressKey ("lalt")
    Sleep(math.random(40, 135))
    PressKey ("X")
    Sleep(math.random(40, 135))
    ReleaseKey ("lalt")
    ReleaseKey ("X")
    Sleep(math.random(40, 135))
    PressKey ("O")
    Sleep(math.random(40, 135))
    ReleaseKey ("O")
    Sleep(200)
    MoveMouseTo( 54436, 55453)
    Sleep(math.random(40, 135))
    PressMouseButton(1)
    ReleaseMouseButton(1)
    Sleep(400)
    MoveMouseTo( 54299, 48650)
       Sleep(150)
       PressMouseButton(1)      
       ReleaseMouseButton(1)
    end
```

Comment: Need more information of library in use. Stock Lua does not have "Sleep()", so... no idea, how to interrupt it.

Comment: Insert lines `if IsKeyLockOn("capslock") then return end` after every `Sleep`.  Now you can exit script by temporarily turning CapsLock LED on.

Comment: Thank you Egor that has worked perfectly